# r subset dataset by date range over multiple years

Tags: r, subset, date-range

I am working with a multi-year dataset that has columns for date (%Y-%m-%d) and daily values for several variables.
In R, how do I subset the data by a date range (i.e., June 29 +/- 5 days) but capture the data from all years?

```
               DATE        A       B      C
1996-06-10 12:00:00    178.0    24.1    1.7

1996-06-11 12:00:00    184.1    30.2    1.1

1996-06-12 12:00:00    187.2    29.4    1.8

1996-06-13 12:00:00    194.4    35.0    5.3

1996-06-14 12:00:00    200.3    35.9    1.5

1996-06-15 12:00:00    138.9    15.1    0.0

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R attempt.

Stealing the example data from the other answer by Kevin:

```
df <- data.frame(
  my_date = seq.Date(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("1999-12-31"), by = 1),
  x = rnorm(3652),
  y = rnorm(3652),
  z = rnorm(3652)
)
```

Set your variables for the selection:

```
month_num <- 6
day_num <- 29
bound <- 5
```

Find the key dates in your range of years:

```
keydates <- as.Date(sprintf(
  "%d-%02d-%02d", 
  do.call(seq, as.list(as.numeric(range(format(df$my_date, "%Y"))))),
  month_num,
  day_num
))
```

Make a selection:

```
out <- df[df$my_date %in% outer(keydates, -bound:bound, `+`),]
```

Check that it worked:

```
table(format(out$my_date, "%m-%d"))
#06-24 06-25 06-26 06-27 06-28 06-29 06-30 07-01 07-02 07-03 07-04 
#   10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
```

One valid value for each day/month for each year 1990 to 1999, centred on "06-29" with a range of 5 days either side

Answer (score 4):

### 1) Base R

Let `yrs` be all unique years in the data and `targets` be each of those years with the target's month and day.  Then create `dates` which contains all dates within `delta` days of any value in `targets`.  Note that `sapply` strips `dates` of its `"Date"` class but that does not matter since it is only subsequently used in `%in%` and that ignores the class. Finally subset `DF` down to those rows whose `DATE` is in `dates`.  No packages are used.

```
# inputs (also DF defined in Note at end)
target <- "06-19"
delta <- 5

DATE <- as.Date(DF$DATE)
yrs <- unique(format(DATE, "%Y"))
targets <- as.Date(paste(yrs, target, sep = "-"))
dates <- c(sapply(targets, "+", seq(-delta, delta)))
DF[DATE %in% dates, ]
```

giving:

```
                 DATE     A    B   C
5 1996-06-14 12:00:00 200.3 35.9 1.5
6 1996-06-15 12:00:00 138.9 15.1 0.0
```

### 2) sqldf

Alternately, this can be done using a single SQL statement. Note that we assume that the `DATE` column is character since the question referred to it being in a particular format.  Now, using the same inputs the inner select generates target dates from each year and then the outer select joins `DF` to those rows within `delta` days of any target date.  We use the H2 database backend here since it has better date support than SQLite.

```
library(sqldf)
library(RH2) 

# inputs (also DF defined in Note at end)
target <- "06-19"
delta <- 5

fn$sqldf("select DF.* from DF
  join (select distinct cast(substr(DATE, 1, 4) || '-' || '$target' as DATE) as target 
        from DF) 
    on cast(substr(DATE, 1, 10) as DATE) between target - $delta and target + $delta")
```

giving:

```
                 DATE     A    B   C
1 1996-06-14 12:00:00 200.3 35.9 1.5
2 1996-06-15 12:00:00 138.9 15.1 0.0
```

We could simplify the SQL somewhat if `DATE` is of R's `"Date"` class. That is, replace the `sqldf` statement above with:

```
DF2 <- transform(DF, DATE = as.Date(DATE))
fn$sqldf("select DF2.* from DF2
  join (select distinct cast(year(DATE) || '-' || '$target' as DATE) as target from DF2) 
    on DATE between target - $delta and target + $delta")
```

giving:

```
        DATE     A    B   C
1 1996-06-14 200.3 35.9 1.5
2 1996-06-15 138.9 15.1 0.0
```

### Note

The input `DF` is assumed to be:

```
DF <- structure(list(DATE = c("1996-06-10 12:00:00", "1996-06-11 12:00:00", 
"1996-06-12 12:00:00", "1996-06-13 12:00:00", "1996-06-14 12:00:00", 
"1996-06-15 12:00:00"), A = c(178, 184.1, 187.2, 194.4, 200.3, 
138.9), B = c(24.1, 30.2, 29.4, 35, 35.9, 15.1), C = c(1.7, 1.1, 
1.8, 5.3, 1.5, 0)), .Names = c("DATE", "A", "B", "C"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lubridate](/questions/tagged/lubridate) intervals to provide valid date ranges and then use a [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) map to run each interval over your data to filter.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)  # only because I've used the "exposition" (%$%) pipe
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(
  my_date = as.POSIXct(
    seq.Date(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("1999-12-31"), by = 1),
    tz = "UTC"
  ),
  x = rnorm(3652),
  y = rnorm(3652),
  z = rnorm(3652)
)

month_num <- 6
day_num <- 29
bound <- 5

date_span <- df %>%
  select(my_date) %>%
  filter(month(my_date) == month_num & day(my_date) == day_num) %>%
  mutate(
    start = my_date - days(bound),
    end = my_date + days(bound)
  ) %$%
  interval(start, end, tzone = "UTC")

map_dfr(date_span, ~filter(df, my_date %within% .x))

# # A tibble: 110 x 4
#    my_date                   x       y       z
#    <dttm>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 1990-06-24 10:00:00  0.404   1.33    1.58  
#  2 1990-06-25 10:00:00  0.351  -1.73    0.665 
#  3 1990-06-26 10:00:00 -0.512   1.01    1.72  
#  4 1990-06-27 10:00:00  1.55    0.417  -0.126 
#  5 1990-06-28 10:00:00  1.86    1.18    0.322 
#  6 1990-06-29 10:00:00 -0.0193 -0.105   0.356 
#  7 1990-06-30 10:00:00  0.844  -0.712   1.51  
#  8 1990-07-01 10:00:00 -0.431   0.451  -2.19  
#  9 1990-07-02 10:00:00  1.74   -0.0650 -0.866 
# 10 1990-07-03 10:00:00  0.965  -0.506  -0.0690
# # ... with 100 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also go via the Julian day, which allows you to do basic arithmetic operations (e.g. ± 5 days) without the need to convert back and forth between `Date` and `character` objects. Keep in mind that your target date translates into a different Julian day during leap years, so you'll need to extract this piece of information somehow (use `lubridate::leap_year` if you don't like the base R approach below):

```r
## convert dates to julian day
dat$JULDAY = format(
  dat$DATE
  , "%j"
)

## target date (here 19 june) as julian day
dat$TARGET = ifelse(
  as.integer(
    format(
      dat$DATE
      , "%y"
    )
  ) %% 4 == 0
  , 171 # leap year
  , 170 # common year
)

## create subset
subset(
  dat
  , JULDAY >= (TARGET - 5) & JULDAY <= (TARGET + 5)
  , select = c("DATE", "A", "B", "C")
)

#         DATE     A    B   C
# 5 1996-06-14 12:00:00 200.3 35.9 1.5
# 6 1996-06-15 12:00:00 138.9 15.1 0.0
```